# How do I create an hyperlink with a PowerShell variable?

Tags: excel, powershell, hyperlink

My code:

```
$cont1 = 0
$arr1  = gci -Path '.\*place1\*place2' -Directory
$arra1 = gci -Path $arr1 -File

"{0}`t{1}`t{2}" -f "Filename", "Hyperlink", "Path" |
    Out-File -FilePath "The Files.csv"

foreach ($Files in $arra1) {
    "{0}`t{1}`t{2}" -f $arra1[$cont1], '=HYPERLINK("$arr1","Go to...")', $arr1[$cont0] |
        Out-File -FilePath "The Files.csv" -Append
    $cont1++
}
```

What I can't do is to make that `$arr1` actually be the entire path of the hyperlink, but of course using the PowerShell variable because I'm using the `Out-File` and the `-Append` to a CSV file. The CSV output should be like this:

```
Filename        Hyperlink        Path
file1           Go to...         C:\somewhere
file2           Go to...         C:\somewhere
etc.
```

So far I could make the code be seen (the output) as an hyperlink, but it points to `$arr1`.

Of course the hyperlinks must be clickable, any help please?

Comment: `'=HYPERLINK("$arr1","Go to...")'` -> ``"=HYPERLINK(`"$arr1`",`"Go to...`")"``

Comment: I've tried with ' but not with `, splendid. Thank you, I was really stuck at this point, how can I make your answer the "best one" or the "correct one"?

Comment: It's just a comment, so it can't be accepted.